# How to have a function return a figure in python (using matplotlib)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Assume that I have some data, and I want to create a plot of this data by passing it to a custom plotting function (myplot()). I am using the matplotlib's modules in myplot().

I would like myplot() to return the handle to a figure, and not plot display the plot when I call this function. Here is a sample code and output from iPython.

[image]

I have two questions regarding this:

1. Why do I still see a plot, even though I am assigning the output of
   myplot() to f?
2. What do I need to supress this plot when I am assigning the output of myplot() to a variable?

Comment: This is only an iPython Notebook feature, right? Because I don't see a plot when I pass the figures around in IDLE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Start ipython with

`ipython notebook`

rather than

`ipython notebook --pylab=inline`

[image]

Comment: I think you do not have to start the whole notebook-session in non-inline-modus. You can control the inline-backend-behaviour with the following command.

    `%config InlineBackend.close_figures = False`

This will prevent your plots from beeing closed (thus shown inside the browser) immediately.

Comment: When you do the plot(t,x) the picture will be shown. Is there a way to generate the picture without it appearing?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to start the whole notebook in non-inline-modus you can just use the following code:

```
%config InlineBackend.close_figures = False

def myplot(t,x):
    fig = figure()
    x = plot(t,x)
    fig.savefig('plot.png') # This is just to show the figure is still generated
    return fig

t = arange(0,6,0.01)
x = sin(t)

f = myplot(t,x)
```

Comment: This did not work. I still get the same output as shown in my question.